# Applying function to Pandas dataframe with groupby ('Too many indexers' error)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to compute `mean` and `var` along `axis=1` of dataframe using only first k columns (compute as `.iloc[:,:-5]`),naively, I would run as:

```
df.groupby('id').agg([lambda x: x.iloc[:,:-5].mean(axis=1), lambda x: x.iloc[:,:-5].var(axis=1)])
```

but it throws the 'too many indexers' error.

**EDIT**

Some data:

```
       0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9             Q1      Q2      Q3     Q4              id
0    3.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0           12.0    0.83    80.0  1.000            11.0
1    3.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0           14.0    1.60    80.0  1.000            11.0
2    3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  5.0           13.0    1.40    75.0  1.000            11.0
3    3.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0           12.0    0.50    80.0  0.848            11.0
4    3.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  7.0  7.0  5.0  4.0  4.0  2.0           13.0    1.74    70.0  0.883            11.0
13   3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  2.0  3.0  3.0           12.0    3.67    45.0  1.000            14.0
14   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0           13.0    3.67    48.0  0.848            14.0
15   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0           12.0    1.67    70.0  0.848            14.0
16   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  2.0           12.0    3.33    60.0  0.848            14.0
17   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0           12.0    3.33    60.0  0.848            14.0
25   4.0  4.0  6.0  5.0  NaN  6.0  4.0  3.0  NaN  4.0           11.0    3.36    85.0  0.796            17.0
26   4.0  5.0  4.0  7.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  6.0  7.0  5.0            8.0    4.76    50.0  0.725            17.0
27   4.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  4.0  5.0  3.0  3.0  5.0            9.0    3.33    50.0  0.725            17.0
28   3.0  4.0  4.0  3.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0           10.0    3.12    75.0  0.725            17.0
29   3.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  2.0           15.0    3.05    79.0  0.725            17.0
39   3.0  3.0  5.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  5.0           12.0    1.19    80.0  0.883            18.0
40   5.0  4.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  5.0  7.0  4.0            9.0    1.83    75.0  0.883            18.0
41   5.0  6.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  7.0  7.0           12.0    1.71    35.0  1.000            18.0
42   5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  NaN  4.0  4.0  3.0  2.0           13.0    0.86    85.0  1.000            18.0
43   3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  5.0  3.0  3.0           11.0    1.36    75.0  1.000            18.0
48   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need first:

```
df['m'] = df.iloc[:,:-5].mean(axis=1)
df['v'] = df.iloc[:,:-5].var(axis=1)
```

and then aggregate if necesary.

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to do it directly from my dataframe, without preparing new columns ('m','v'). Is it possible at all?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if understand your question. do you need aggregate by column `id` ? Is possible add some sample?

Comment: please see the edited post, where I added some data. I need to compute mean and var along axis=1 for each 'id'. I am sorry, if I am not clear.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused. What is desired output if dont need new columns?

Comment: Oh boy, I confused myself!!! Sure, thanks for asking. Now it's clear and I will remove the question. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much. But I think still is possible aggregate like  `df = df.groupby('id')['v','m'].sum()` - but it depends what you need. Nice day!

Comment: I wanted to (practice) apply different functions using groupby along a particular axis on particular columns. Is it possible?

Comment: I think partly yes. But `agg` is not implemented. so you can try: `np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('AABBB'))
print (df)` and then `print (df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).mean())`

Comment: then groupby by duplicated columns names and aggregate. also it works if has multiindex in columns.

Comment: that's interesting, need to check it. Another question: how to reorder columns in correlation matrix? (pd.corr()). By default, it orders in alphabetical order, how to change it?

Comment: Unfortunately now I am on phone only. But works `df = df.reindex(columns=['C','B','D'])` - use custom order of columns nsmes.